# I have problem with cursor position after using this macro

Tags: texstudio

I use TexStudio and have created the following macro: [image]

```
%SCRIPT

env = triggerMatches\[1\]

txt = "\\begin{"+env+"}\n"

txt = txt+"\n" 

txt = txt+"\\end{"+env+"}"

cursor.insertText(txt)

cursor.movePosition(1, cursorEnums.Up)

cursor.movePosition(1, cursorEnums.StartOfLine)
```

with trigger: `begin(\S+)\s`

So when I write `begindefinition` and click space the result is:

```
\begin{definition}

| 

\end{definition}
```

but when I do the same thing after a tap space the result is:

```
(four spaces) \begin{definition}

| (without spaces before cursor)

\end{definition} (without spaces before \end)
```

Comment: Type `cursor.movePosition(1, cursorEnums.StartOfLine)` on the line before `cursor.insertText(txt)`.

Comment: But when I used the trigger after a space the result is like this (for example after tap space)
![Screenshot 2023-06-27 093736](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/assets/132083925/95fae6c1-b0aa-421a-b86f-85ae0796f5c1)
and what I want is this :

![Screenshot 2023-06-27 093736](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/assets/132083925/e29e350c-eca1-4423-b703-8ec4e2c3c0fd)

Comment: I have removed the [tag:macros] tag as this is reserved to TeX macros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like that?

```
%SCRIPT
spaces = ""
for (var i=1;i<=cursor.columnNumber();i++) spaces = spaces + "\t";
cursor.insertText("\\begin{"+triggerMatches[1]+"}\n"+spaces+spaces+"\n"+spaces+"\\end{"+triggerMatches[1]+"}")
cursor.movePosition(1, cursorEnums.Up)
```

Trigger: `begin(\S+)\s`

Comment: The problem is that cursor.columnNumber() account tap space as 1 only not 4 spaces

Comment: @Rabah In this case, replace the space with a tab. I modified the code.

Comment: Thank you! I modified your code, and now I have achieved the desired result. Here's the updated code that works perfectly for me.  https://imgur.com/A58q7Ee